# Dynamically adding custom Views to TableLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, tablelayout

I'm trying to dynamically add custom Views to TableLayout. Adding things like TextView works but when I'm trying to inflate my own I see a blank screen.
I saw similar questions but none of them had was any helpful.
I have a layout which is inflated into a Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/gameTableLayout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

And then I am dynamically adding row into this table in the Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    tableLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gameTableLayout);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(trParams);
    for (int i =0; i <3; i++) {
        View cardView = li.inflate(R.layout.card_covered_layout, null);
        row.addView(cardView);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(row);
}
```

This is the R.layout.card_covered_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/cardCoveredLayout"
              android:layout_width="50dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_margin="3dp"
              android:background="@drawable/card_covered_background"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the card_covered_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color= "@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```